# To control subplot with plotly express

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

```py
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

tips= px.data.tips()

fig = make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,shared_yaxes=True)

bar1 = px.bar(tips, x="sex", y="total_bill",
             color='smoker',
             barmode ='group',title = 'Group')

bar2= px.bar(tips, x="sex", y="total_bill",
             color='smoker',
             barmode ='stack',title = 'Relative')

bar2.update_traces(showlegend=False)
fig.add_trace(bar1.data[0],row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(bar1.data[1],row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(bar2.data[0],row=1,col=2)
fig.add_trace(bar2.data[1],row=1,col=2)
```

[image]

I made a bar graph with a plotly express, one with a 'group type' and the other with a 'stack type'. I want to subplot this, but there's no way to express stacks (overlay as well) and do you have any advice here?

Comment: interesting, `barmode` is a **layout** parameter, not a **trace** or **axis** parameter.  So I don't see anyway to achieve what you want

Comment: I agree with @RobRaymond Just tried to find a solution as well and came to the same result. Think about posting this in the plotly commuity forum!